# ¿Como puedo contar los registros segun la consulta?

Tags: php, mysql

//Estoy intentando contar el numero de registro de la base de datos segun la situacion.[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

```
<?php
$conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","admin123","database");
```

?>

Estadisticas


    
            .body {
                width: 100%;
            }

```
        .table {     
            font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
            font-size: 12px;    
            margin: 45px;     
            width: 90%; 
            text-align: left;    
            border-collapse: collapse; 
        }
        .td {    
            padding: 8px;     
            background: #e8edff;     
            border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
            color: #669;    
            border-top: 1px solid transparent; 
        }

        .tr:hover td { 
            background: #d0dafd; 
            color: #339; 
        }
        .submit{
            background: #33384a;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 10px
        }
        .submit:hover{
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        @media(max-width: 480px){
            form{
                width: 100%;
            }           
        }  
</style>
```

query($consulta);
    $fila=$resultado->fetch_assoc(); //que te devuelve un array asociativo con el nombre del campo

    $totalServicios = $fila['totalServicios']; //Este es el valor que acabas de calcular en la consulta

?>
 query($consulta);
    $fil=$resultado->fetch_assoc(); //que te devuelve un array asociativo con el nombre del campo

    $totalProgramados = $fil['Programado']; //Este es el valor que acabas de calcular en la consulta
?>
 query($consulta);
    $fil=$resultado->fetch_assoc(); //que te devuelve un array asociativo con el nombre del campo

    $totalProgramados = $fil['Fallido']; //Este es el valor que acabas de calcular en la consulta
?>

## Estadisticas De Servicios

Servicios Solicitados 
                 Servicios Programados 
                 Servicios Fallidos 
                 Servicios Cancelados

```
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $fila['totalServicios']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fil['Programado']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fil['Fallido']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema?  Y... ¿por qué conectas dos veces a la base de datos? Puedes usar la misma conexión para todas las consultas que necesites en el script y al final cierras los recursos.

Comment: el problema es que necesito contar el numero de registros segun la situacion  es decir cuantos estan Realizados cuantos programados

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78537/discussion-on-question-by-cristian-antonio-trujillo-gris-como-puedo-contar-los).